# PEX(Python) packaging without an entry point

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a small python script (without modules) that I want to package via pex and execute. However, i could not find any option in the documentation (https://pex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildingpex.html) to package script without an entry point

I am using the following command

```
pex requests ./app -o app.pex --python-shebang '#!/usr/bin/env python3.9'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out that it is not possible hence i created a module and a main function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setuptools with PEX.

Flow `setup.py` sample:

```
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages

    setup(
    name='cli',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'cli=pkgname.main:cli',
        ],
    }
   )
```

**And run this in terminal:**

```
$ python setup.py bdist_pex --bdist-all
```